# Delete item from database with C# using HttpDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-delete, http-delete

I am trying to delete a row from my database based on a Primary Key ID field. When I try to do it, all of the code executes without any errors, but the item doesn't get deleted from the database.

I'm passing the item to my C# backend from an angular frontend call like this:

```
delete(customerId: number, materialCustomerId: number): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.getBaseUrl()}/${customerId}/materialcustomer/${materialCustomerId}`).catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

It then hits my controller method:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{customerId}/materialcustomer/{materialCustomerId}")]
    [AccessControl(Securable.Customer, Permissions.Delete, Permissions.Execute)]
    public async Task Delete(int customerId, int materialCustomerId)
    {
        await _materialCustomerDeleter.DeleteAsync(MaterialCustomer.CreateWithOnlyId(materialCustomerId), HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    }
```

Manipulator method:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(MaterialCustomer model, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));

        await _materialCustomerDeleter.DeleteAsync(new TblMaterialCustomer { MaterialCustomerId = model.MaterialCustomerId }, cancellationToken);

        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        await _customerWriter.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

and finally, my repository method:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(TblMaterialCustomer entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var item =
            await _context.TblMaterialCustomer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.MaterialCustomerId == entity.MaterialCustomerId, cancellationToken);

        if (item == null || cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        _context.SetModified(item);

    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `_context.SetModified` ? Why not `Remove` on the DbSet? You should also call SaveAsync to persist the change. Also you should probably return a result from the web api/mvc method like 200.

Comment: @Igor my SetModified method `public virtual void SetModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            if (Entry(entity).State != EntityState.Modified)
                Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }` Sets the EntityState on an enum where 2 = Deleted, 3 = modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `await _customerWriter.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);` calls through to the same DbContext instance and calls method `SaveAsync` you should re-write the delete method like this:

```
public void Delete(TblMaterialCustomer entity)
{
    _context.TblMaterialCustomer.Remove(entity);
}
```

Also it would probably be a good idea to return a result from the WebAPI call, although it is not required, like OK/200.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int customerId, int materialCustomerId)
{
    await _materialCustomerDeleter.DeleteAsync(MaterialCustomer.CreateWithOnlyId(materialCustomerId), HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    return Ok();
}
```